# Python: Possible to pass a list of values to an if statement?

Tags: python, pandas

I am merging multiple excel sheets into a pandas DataFrame and extracting the email address from a Report_Name column.  I have been able to execute what I need but the hardship is that there are over 5000 email addresses that I would have to run checks against (in this example only five).  While I could type out all the conditions for these, it's not practical.

So my question is:
Can I pass a single list that includes these 5000 email addresses as a condition (somehow) in an if statement?  Below is my code of how I am currently doing it.

```
| **Report_Name**                                    |
|--------------------------------------------------- |
|SYN-Laptops-Nov10 (002)                             |
|something_offer bozo@domain.com                     |
|another thing foxtrot@domain.com                    |
|my offer is attached ooo 12-31 rocksteps@domain.com |
|copy of offer dolphin@domain.com                    |
|private offering copy chomps@domain.com             |
```

```
#----------- extract the email address from the Report Name column -----------#

#blank list to collect and store the email addresses
collected_emails = []

#----------- For Loop to iterate through the values under the ['Report_Name'] column -----------#
for report_name_value in excel_df['Report_Name']:
    if 'bozo@domain.com' in report_name_value:
        collected_emails.append('bozo@domain.com')
    elif 'foxtrot@domain.com' in report_name_value:
        collected_emails.append('foxtrot@domain.com')
    elif 'rocksteps@domain.com' in report_name_value:
        collected_emails.append('rocksteps@domain.com')
    elif 'dolphin@domain.com' in report_name_value:
        collected_emails.append('dolphin@domain.com')
    elif 'chomps@domain.com' in report_name_value:
        collected_emails.append('chomps@domain.com')
    else:
        collected_emails.append('No Email Address')

#create DataFrame for the collected emails
collected_emails_df = pd.DataFrame(collected_emails, columns = ['Email_Address'])

#create master_df to concat both the excel_df and collected_emails_df together
master_df = pd.concat([excel_df, collected_emails_df,], axis = 1)     

#export master DataFrame to an excel file and save it on the SharePoint directory
master_df.to_excel(output_local+'Offers.xlsx', index=False)}
```

**RESULT**

```
| **Report_Name**                                     |    **Email_Address**       |
| SYN-Laptops-Nov10 (002)                             |    No Email Address        |
| something_offer bozo@domain.com                     |    bozo@domain.com         |
| another thing foxtrot@domain.com                    |    foxtrot@domain.com      |
| my offer is attached ooo 12-31 rocksteps@domain.com |    rocksteps@domain.com    |
| copy of offer dolphin@domain.com                    |    dolphin@domain.com      |
| private offering copy chomps@domain.com             |    chomps@domain.com       |
```

I am a beginner with python and was unable to pull up any references of how to tackle this problem specifically.  Hence the post.  Thanks for your time and I appreciate any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good case for lambda and filter!

```
list_to_check = ['bozo@domain.com', ...] # Pass this in to your function

is_match_func = lambda x: x in excel_df['Report_Name']

all_matches = list(filter(is_match_func, list_to_check))

for email in all_matches:
    collected_emails.append(email)
```

Comment: fyi, I applied your code sample and I received an error on the all_matches variable.  TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: @EricGeraghty, chiming in here. Not sure where your error comes from, but the second line above needs to be `is_match_func = lambda x: x in excel_df['Report_Name'].values`. Without `.values`, the function will check if a value in the index of the series, not among its values.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
# df
                                         Report_Name
0                            SYN-Laptops-Nov10 (002)
1                    something_offer bozo@domain.com
2                   another thing foxtrot@domain.com
3  my offer is attached ooo 12-31 rocksteps@domai...
4                   copy of offer dolphin@domain.com
5            private offering copy chomps@domain.com
```

Doing:

```
df['Emails'] = df.Report_Name.str.extract('(\w+@\w+\.\w+)')
print(df)
```

- [Regex Explanation](https://regexr.com/6v1a1) - basically, we know that there aren't spaces in an email, and that they all contain [chars `@` chars `.` chars]

Output:

```
                                         Report_Name                Emails
0                            SYN-Laptops-Nov10 (002)                   NaN
1                    something_offer bozo@domain.com       bozo@domain.com
2                   another thing foxtrot@domain.com    foxtrot@domain.com
3  my offer is attached ooo 12-31 rocksteps@domai...  rocksteps@domain.com
4                   copy of offer dolphin@domain.com    dolphin@domain.com
5            private offering copy chomps@domain.com     chomps@domain.com
```

It's not clear what you want to do after this point...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [**`pandas.Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regular expression to extract all the emails.

Try this :

```
collected_emails = (
                    excel_df['Report_Name']
                     .str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+@.+\.com)')
                     .dropna()
                     .squeeze()
                     .tolist()
                    )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(collected_emails)

['bozo@domain.com', 'foxtrot@domain.com', 'rocksteps@domain.com', 'dolphin@domain.com', 'chomps@domain.com']
```